# Filtering in Spree 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I need product properties' filters on taxon's show page.

Heres's what i've added to my *spree/taxon_controller.rb* show method:

```
if params[:filter].present?
  params[:filter].each do |k,v|
    pp=@product_properties.where("property_id = ? and value in (?)", @properties.find_by(name: k), v).pluck(:id)
    @products = @products.joins(:product_properties).where("spree_product_properties.id in (?)", pp)
  end
end
```

I trying to do similiar query in console:

```
Spree::Product.joins(:product_properties).where("spree_product_properties.id  in ?", [3,23]).where("spree_product_properties.id  = ?", 4)
```

But it returned nothing.

If delete last where-statement, it's all ok

```
Spree::Product.joins(:product_properties).where("spree_product_properties.id  in ?", [3,23])
```

One product object contain product_properties with id 3 and 4.
What i do wrong?

P.S. First i try to use spree's filter system with custom search as it write [here](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/cc73b88699c9c6b45a95), but it didn't work at all.

P.P.S I think filters is preetty stndart feature for e-shop, why it so many problems with them in spree?!